# Not moving from GameViewController Menu to GameScene Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I made my game Menu in GameViewController. Then I try to move to GameScene when the Go button has been pressed. I use the default code for presenting the GameScene file.

```
 if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

         // Configure the view.
         let skView = self.view as! SKView
         skView.showsFPS = false
         skView.showsNodeCount = false

         /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
         skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

         /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
         scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

         skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

I have the Menu made in the Storyboard. I think this is why it isn't working. How should I fix this?

Niall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SpriteKit we use scenes, the GameScene is above in GameViewController. 
The GameViewController show you the GameScene.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. This code is a play function in my Menu (GameViewController) . I have a problem when I try to execute the move to GameScene

Comment: You made the menu on GameViewController, the menu will be on the GameScene not on GameViewController

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to reply. I just re-made the menu on the GameScene